# Wifi interface seemingly disabling itself?

Tags: networking, drivers

When I booted my laptop today the Wifi suddenly wasn't working and I've been trying for the last two hours to make it work again. I think I fixed an issue or two down the way but I didn't really document anything. The problem I'm unable to solve now is this: My Wifi interface seems to be disabled and I can't (always??) enable it. But even when I was able to enable it the Wifi still wasn't working.

This is my output of `lshw -C network`:

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 0c
       serial: 30:65:ec:78:53:5c
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c1200000-c1200fff memory:c1000000-c1003fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7265
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 48
       serial: 5c:e0:c5:03:6c:ea
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-88-generic firmware=17.3216344376.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:48 memory:c1100000-c1101fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:1.2
       logical name: usb0
       serial: ce:4f:d0:53:fc:10
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.231.76 link=yes multicast=yes
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

Output of `sudo rfkill list`:

```
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
5: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Output of `sudo systemctl status wpa_supplicant.service`:

```
● wpa_supplicant.service - WPA supplicant
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-10-02 15:42:54 CEST; 5h 5min ago
   Main PID: 1242 (wpa_supplicant)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9378)
     Memory: 3.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/wpa_supplicant.service
             └─1242 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant

Okt 02 15:42:54 Lithographie systemd[1]: Starting WPA supplicant...
Okt 02 15:42:54 Lithographie wpa_supplicant[1242]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Okt 02 15:42:54 Lithographie systemd[1]: Started WPA supplicant.
```

The first is my Ethernet connection that I don't use. The second is my wireless connection that miraculously stopped working today. The third is my workaround Tethering connection through my Phone.

`modprobe -r iwlwifi` and `modprobe iwlwifi` didn't work first, now they do but it didn't really change anything
Also, when I try `sudo ip link set wlp2s0 up` sometimes it switches the interface to enabled (sometimes it doesn't), but still, Wifi isn't working.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on an Acer Travelmate P236-M-57R4.
Thanks for helping in advance!

Edit: Don't know if there is any connection, but I had some issues yesterday with the very unwise decision to `chown -r` my /usr/-folder with my main account. I think I resolved these, but maybe I didn't?

Comment: can you edit your question with the output of `sudo systemctl status wpa_supplicant.service` ? `wpa_supplicant` - Wi-Fi Protected Access client and IEEE 802.1X supplicant,

Comment: Does it start working when you run from a Terminal, `sudo rfkill unblock-all'?

Comment: Thank you folks for your ideas! Those were actually among those I tried, I added the outputs above

Comment: I have a feeling your `chown` command may have modified permissions on some configuration used for network management, I'm afraid. Especially if the issues happened only after running that command.

Comment: Oh no, that's what I feared. Can you give me a clue to find out what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `chown` command was the problem, I figure. Got it with `sudo apt-get purge wpasupplicant` and re-installing with `sudo apt-get install wpasupplicant` and `sudo apt-get install network-manager` (installing from cache).